# UNKNOWN ERROR: Playing Audio in an HTML code if a condition satisfies

Tags: html, flask

I am attempting to create a music player in case a condition is satisfied. The first part is definitely working in my code. However, I get an unknown error when I am pressing on the play button.

That is my code! bac is just the input of the user. The song file is in a subdirectory called static. The html file is in a subdirectory called templates, since I am using flask

```
{% if bac > 0.4 %}
    <audio controls>
        <audio src="static/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: try: `<audio src="{{url_for('static', filename='song.ogg')}}" type="audio/ogg">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried doing that but still the song is not being played.
ERROR MESSAGE: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser's dev tools: look for that 404 and confirm the path is generated as `/static/song.ogg` and the file exsists.  You could also do this by viewing the page's source in the browser.